# How can I set the value of a Series at a specific in a chainable style?

Tags: python, pandas, method-chaining

I can't figure how to set the value of a Series at a specific index in a chainable style.

For example, say I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [0,0,0]})
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  0
1  2  0
2  3  0
```

If I want to change all the values of a column in a pipeline, I can use `pandas.DataFrame.assign()`:

```
>>> df.assign(b=[4,5,6])
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

...and then I can do other stuff with the dataframe on the same line, for example:

```
>>> df.assign(b=[4,5,6]).mul(100)
     a    b
0  100  400
1  200  500
2  300  600
```

---

But I can't do this for an individual value at a specific in a Series.

```
>>> s = df['a']
>>> s
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

I can, of course, just use a normal Python assignment operation using `=`:

```
>>> s[1] = 9
>>> s
0    1
1    9
2    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

But the problems with that are:

- It's in-place, so it modifies my existing dataframe
- Assignment statements using `=` are not allowed in Python lambda functions

For example, what if I wanted to do this:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x['b', 0] = 13, axis=1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    df.apply(lambda x: x['b', 0] = 13, axis=1)
             ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

(I understand that there are better ways to that particular case, but this is just a made-up example.)

**How can I set the value at the specified index of a Series?** I would like to be able to just to something like `s.set_value(idx, 'my_val')` and have it return the modified (copied) Series.

Comment: Not the best but `apply` takes in a series so you have `name` and `index`:`df.apply(lambda x: np.where(x.index==0, 13, x) if x.name=='b' else x)`

Comment: Cool, that's long for such a simple task but it indeed works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to return a copy of the column with the item at the specified index.

This is basically like using `.loc`:

```py
>>> df['b'].where(df['b'].index != 1, 13)
0     0
1    13
2     0
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

If you have an index that isn't a `RangeIndex` or that doesn't start from zero, you can call `reset_index()` before `where()`, which will be like the above for `.loc` only mimicking the behavior of `.iloc` instead:

```py
>>> s = pd.Series({'a': 0, None: 0, True: 0})
>>> s
a       0
NaN     0
True    0
dtype: int64

>>> s.where(s.reset_index().index != 1, 13)
a        0
NaN     13
True     0
dtype: int64
```