# How does one use an assignment expression in a dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have the below data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
             [100,90,80,70,36,45],
             [101,78,65,88,55,78],
             [92,77,42,79,43,32],
             [103,98,76,54,45,65]],
             index = pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', periods=4)
    )
   
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
            (("mkf", "Open"),
             ("mkf", "Close"),
             ("tdf", "Open"),
             ("tdf","Close"),
             ("ghi","Open"),
             ("ghi", "Close"))
   )
```

And then I execute the following dictionary comprehension:

```
{c:df[c].assign(r=np.log(df[(c, 'Close')]).diff()) for c in df.columns.levels[0]}

{'ghi':             Open  Close         r
 2022-01-01    36     45       NaN
 2022-01-02    55     78  0.550046
 2022-01-03    43     32 -0.890973
 2022-01-04    45     65  0.708651,
 'mkf':             Open  Close         r
 2022-01-01   100     90       NaN
 2022-01-02   101     78 -0.143101
 2022-01-03    92     77 -0.012903
 2022-01-04   103     98  0.241162,
 'tdf':             Open  Close         r
 2022-01-01    80     70       NaN
 2022-01-02    65     88  0.228842
 2022-01-03    42     79 -0.107889
 2022-01-04    76     54 -0.380464}
```

How would one produce the same result with an assignment expression (i.e. the symbol `:=` )?

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-assignment-expressions-in-python

Comment: What's your goal? I'm having trouble understanding quite what you're trying to do.

Comment: @richardec Am trying to replicate the result produced by the dictionary comprehension with a slight wrinkle.  The wrinkle is to use the assignment expression operator which was recently introduced in python 3.8.

Comment: What do you want to use it on? The dictionary, the values of the dict, the dataframes...what?

Comment: @richardec I want to use it to assign the new column , `r` , that is created in the body of the above comprehension to the dataframes that are the values in the dictionary. Rather than using the `.assign` method...

Comment: That's not what assignment expressions are for. The way you do it now is ok. You don't need assignment expressions ;)

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not sure this is possible: `SyntaxError: cannot use assignment expressions with subscript` with `{c: (df[(c, 'r')] := np.log(df[(c, 'Close')]).diff()) for c in df.columns.levels[0]}`

Comment: @mozway Ok.  According to the article they can be used to assign vales in a comprehension. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-assignment-expressions-in-python

Comment: No it doesn't make sense here at all. AE are only to assign to a variable while returning the value. Out of topic here.

Comment: @mozway Ok, thanks.

Comment: @jgg you can use AE in dictionary comprehensions for sure, but not for what you want to do. Only to assign a variable. Not to mutate an object.

Comment: @mozway How does one learn to make these kind of distinctions?

Comment: @jgg, well, by experience! You tried to use `:=`, but you couldn't. Looking at your question history for today, I see you're trying to do functional-programming-ish with Python+pandas, and I can tell you that using `assign` is perfect for such a task. It was designed for this very purpose.

Comment: I've always wished there were something so convenient like that for setting values of Series objects...I even asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70281456/17242583) about it.